# Loop through a void**

Tags: c, sorting, pointers, void

I would like to make an update to my Insertion by calculating the size into the method and not by passing it as parameter. How do I can loop into a void**? Or are there specific methods to calculate the dimension of the array?

```
void insertion_sort(int size, void** array, CompFunction compare){
    int i,j;
    void* key;
    for(i = 1; i<size;i++){
        key = array[i];
        for(j = i-1; j>=0 && compare(array[j],key)>=0;j--){
            swap(&array[j+1],&array[j]);
        }
        array[j+1] = key;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is argument a problem?

Comment: usually array of pointers are terminated by `NULL` or the size is given

Comment: Salvaging this question would be a new question.

Comment: You are attempting something similar to `sort()`, why not see how that handles this problem.

Comment: Unrelated: C does not support _methods_. And what do you mean with "loop through a `void **`"? You cannot loop through a pointer.

Comment: @Neil Or rather, `qsort()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to make an update to my Insertion by calculating the size into the method and not by passing it as parameter. How do I can loop into a `void**`? Or are there specific methods to calculate the dimension of the array?

Your function is not *receiving* an array.  It is receiving a pointer (to a `void *`).  Supposing that the received pointer is valid, the object to which it points can be considered to be the first element of an array (even if it's declared by the caller as a scalar), but the pointer does not convey the length of that array.  You must communicate that separately.  The most common techniques for that are:

1. Passing the length as a separate parameter, as you demonstrate, or
2. Including an end-of-data sentinel value as the last in the array, as the standard library's string functions expect you to do.

Unless the length is somehow encoded into the pointed-to array elements themselves (e.g. via a sentinel), the called function cannot determine the array size from a pointer alone.  Think about that for a moment, as it stands to logic entirely on its own.